# Adding javascript to html file loaded by file_get_contents in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am loading a html file by file_get_contents and make some changes over it and then echo it. I want to add a javascript code to the file but I don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/index.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$node = $doc->getElementById('something');
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
echo $doc->saveHtml($doc), PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: Apparently you already know how to load a DOM and remove a node. That's not very different from adding a node. A script tag is just an HTML node with text (code) in it.

Comment: I somehow get the feeling you're trying to make phishing site, that 's going to mimic the real site and send the users password to you...

Comment: I have checked $dom->createElement and $dom->appendChild but I couldn't make it work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$page = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($page);

$head = $doc->getElementsByTagName("head")->item(0);

$js = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$js->appendXml("<script> alert(1); </script>");
$head->appendChild($js);

echo $doc->saveHtml();

?>
```

This adds `<script> alert(1); </script>` to . Of course you can use "getElementById" and it be will exactly the same.

Hope this helps.