# insert custom script file into <head> tag in php file obtained with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I would like to be able to modify elements in a DOM that I actually obtained using php function file_get_contents(). My way to go is actually try to insert a script tag into the  but I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::parent()
```

That's my code:

```
$html=str_get_html(file_get_contents('http://www.elpais.com/'));
foreach($html->find('head') as $header) {
        $document = new DOMDocument();
        $element = $document->createElement('script');
        $script = $document->createTextNode('console.log("new custom script added!");');
        $element->appendChild($script);
        $header->appendChild($element);
        echo $document->saveHTML($document->childNodes[0]);
}
```

If anyone would now why appendChild on $header is not working or a better way to do it, I would be very grateful for the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean run a specific file?if so, add a file in your script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ur_file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem was that I had code being executed in the script after jquery document.ready and since was not being executed, I thought it was a problem with the loading of the file. Everything solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the way to do it here:

[Adding javascript to html file loaded by file_get_contents in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886405/adding-javascript-to-html-file-loaded-by-file-get-contents-in-php)

Now I'm trying to call a script file, instead of injecting a function inside the  tag, with no success.
Anyone knows a way to do it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That's the code for appending an existing .js file to a header taken with a php file_get_contents().
As I had a JQuery document ready function was not being executed and I thought it was wrong. The following code adds jquery before loading the script and then executes the script with the document.ready

```
$html=str_get_html(file_get_contents('http://www.elpais.com/'));
foreach($html->find('head') as $header) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHtml($page);
    $head = $doc->getElementsByTagName("head")->item(0);

    $js = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $js->appendXml("<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js\"></script>");
    $js->appendXml("<script src=\"js/script.js\"></script> ");
    $head->appendChild($js);
    echo $doc->saveHtml();
}
```